# AWS - connect to PostgreSQL from Python not working

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, boto3, psycopg2

Sorry to bother you, but I have been struggling to use Python to connect to the AWS PostgreSQL database based on this instruction https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Python.html, as it always displays timeout error.

I have also set up a config file in ~/.aws folder to configure the boto3, with the following:

```
[default] 
aws_access_key_id = X
aws_secret_access_key = X
```

```
import os
import boto3
import psycopg2

ENDPOINT="url"
PORT="5432"
USR="kaggle"
REGION="us-east-2a"
os.environ['LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN'] = '1'

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
client = boto3.client('rds',region_name=REGION)

token = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=ENDPOINT, Port=PORT, DBUsername=USR, Region=REGION)

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=ENDPOINT, port=PORT, user=USR, password=token)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT now()""")
    query_results = cur.fetchall()
    print(query_results)
except Exception as e:
    print("Database connection failed due to {}".format(e))
```

The error is:

```
Database connection failed due to could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on host "url" (IP) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: NEVER reveal your credentials _anywhere_! Please immediately disable those credentials in your IAM console!

Comment: Where is this code running (EC2, your own computer)? Is the Amazon RDS database configured as `Publicly Accessible = Yes`? Have you been able to connect to the database in any other way (eg using an SQL client)?

Comment: I am running this code on my own computer. I have configured it as Publicly Accessible. I tried to connect to the database using this SQL server, but it also shows connection failed. (https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-connect-postgresql-db/?nc1=h_ls)

Comment: do you have telnet installed. if yes try `telnet endpointUrl 5432` . Also in the RDS's security group, make sure that your public ip address is allowed in the In Bound rules

Answer (score 1):

It appears your scenario is:

- An Amazon RDS database in a VPC with `Publicly Accessible = Yes`
- Your own computer on the Internet (outside of AWS)
- You want to connect to Amazon RDS from your computer

Things to check:

- Amazon RDS has been **launched in a public subnet** (defined as a subnet with a Route Table entry that points to an Internet Gateway)
- You are using the **DNS Name** of the RDS database to connect (as provided in the RDS console)
- A **Security Group** on the RDS database that permits inbound access on port 5432 to [your computer's public IP address](http://whatismyip.akamai.com/), or to `0.0.0.0/0` (but that is bad from a security perspective)